# Closed form for $\sqrt {-1\sqrt {-2 \sqrt {-3 \sqrt {-4 \ldots}}}}$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, closed-form

Does $\sqrt {-1\sqrt {-2 \sqrt {-3 \sqrt {-4 \ldots}}}}$ converge?
Is there a closed form for it?

Comment: Before asking whether the infinite expression converges, you should probably explain what you expect a finite piece like $\sqrt{-1 \sqrt{-2}}$ to mean.  That's a lot of branch cuts you're chaining together...

Comment: We can write your constant as $$\prod^{\infty}_{k=1} (-k)^{\frac{1}{2^k}}$$ One may take out all the minus signs and say it is equal to $-S$, where $S$ is Somos' quadratic recurrence constant. However if the product is divergent we can not do that.

Comment: Why my comment explaining which branch to use was deleted?

Answer (score 1):

[Somos' quadratic recurrence constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html) does converge and there is no closed form. The sequence you give does not converge as the differences between successive terms are always greater than 1/2 .